# Wildcard search on nested object in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we are storing objects of type vehicle which have a reference to a type owner in the following structure. Then Running the following request:

`POST: localhost:9200/15/vehicles/_search'

with the following body:

```
 { "query": { "wildcard": {"make":"*toy*"} }}
```

returns the relevant objects:

```
     "took": 5,
     "timed_out": false,
     "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
     },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "15.index",
            "_type": "vehicle",
            "_id": "352",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "id": "352",
                "name": "toyota",
                "owner_id": "12",
                "owner": {
                    "id": "12",
                    "name": "John Smith",
                    "login_id": 1,
                    "active": true,
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am now attempting to query by nested object (e.g. all vehicles that belong to user John Smith)

```
 {"query": {"wildcard": {"owner.name": "*John*"}}}
```

returns no results, while:

```
 {"query": {"wildcard": {"owner": {"name": "*John*"}}}}
```

errors out with:

```
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {....
  [4]: SearchParseException[....
  Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ \"query\": { \"wildcard\": {\"owner\": {\"name\":\"*ab*\"} }}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[....
 [wildcard] query does not support [name]]; }{....
 [3]: SearchParseException[....
: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ \"query\": { \"wildcard\": {\"owner\": {\"name\":\"*ab*\"} }}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[....
 [wildcard] query does not support [name]]; }{....
 [2]: SearchParseException[....
 ]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ \"query\": { \"wildcard\": {\"owner\": {\"name\":\"*ab*\"} }}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[....
 [wildcard] query does not support [name]]; }{....
 : SearchParseException[[....
: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ \"query\": { \"wildcard\": {\"owner\": {\"name\":\"*ab*\"} }}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[....
 [wildcard] query does not support [name]]; }{....
 [0]: SearchParseException[....: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ \"query\": { \"wildcard\": {\"owner\": {\"name\":\"*ab*\"} }}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[.... [wildcard] query does not support [name]]; }]",
"status": 400
```

What is the correct format for a query (wildcard or otherwise) against a nested object? How specifically do wildcard queries differ from that template (if at all)?

Comment: your query string json is not valid. Try {"query": {"wildcard": {"owner": {"name": "*John*"}}}}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to used a [Nested Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to query fields within `nested` types.

```
{
  "query":{
    "nested":{
      "path":"owner",
      "query":{
        "wildcard":{
           "owner.name":"John*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't start your term with a wildcard as it can result in extremely slow queries.

If you have multiple levels of `nested` objects the `path` value should be the deepest level of `nested` objects, and the property in the query should be the full path.

```
{
  "query":{
    "nested":{
      "path":"owner.pets",
      "query":{
        "wildcard":{
           "owner.pets.name":"{someValue}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! out of curiosity, if I wanted to nest multiple levels deep, would I just recurse the same approach? (e.g.:
nested: { path: "owner", query: { nested: path: "pet", query: wildcard: { "owner.pet.name": ... ?

Comment: I have answered your question in the main answer above.

Comment: I have the same nested structure but getting empty results using the above search query using wildcard? @DanTuffery Do you need the sample data that I have?

Answer (score 0):

To combine other conditions with `nested` object, help this help some one.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "fields": [
              "field_a",
              "field_b",
              "field_c"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "students",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "students.name": {
                        "value": "*keyword*"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```